# MongoDB Aggregation filter by subdocument field matching regex

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection shaped like:

```
{
  process: {
    steps: [{
      stepType: '<one of `basic`,`input` or `i(***key***)`'
    }]
  }
}
```

and I want to query to end up with the count of steps by step type. I currently have the following for the basic and input steps which works great:

```
{
  "$project": {
    "process.name": 1,
    "basicSteps": {
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$process.steps",
          "as": "items",
          "cond": { 
            "$eq": [ "$$items.stepType", "basic" ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "inputSteps": {
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$process.steps",
          "as": "items",
          "cond": { 
            "$eq": [ "$$items.stepType", "input" ] 
          }
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
```

For the integration step, I need to match using a regex.. I've tried using $regexMatch or $match with a regex inside but get `Unrecognized expression '$regexMatch'` when doing so. Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: _I want to query to end up with the count of steps by step type._: You can use `$unwind` and then `$group` for this (which is much simpler). But, what is this : _For the integration step, I need to match using a regex..._ (not clear, may be post the code you had tried).

Comment: @prasad_ since the `stepType` will be like `i(example1)` or `i(example2)` I cant just do a normal $eq, I need to match based on regex